# Web 8 Audience Manager Installation

Tags: web8, audience-manager, database, installation

While I am trying to Upgrade Audience Manager Database using the "Upgrade Extended Details in Audience Manager database.ps1" I am getting the following error."cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is null. can you please help me in resolving the issue.[image]

Comment: Looks like you're missing a parameter in that ps command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command I have previously used is:

```
D:\Install\SDL Web 8.1.1 release\Database\mssql> & '.\Upgrade Extended Details in Audience Manager database.ps1' -Configuration
File D:\Install\OutboundEmail.xml -Verbose
```

It's very important to pass in the OutboundEmail.xml file as in Web 8 the Architecture of the Audience Manager XML / DB has changed, and now the Extended Fields are in the database and not in the XML.